# Data wrong display using @antv/g2plot.js version 2+

Tags: javascript, graph, antv, g2plot

I have been trying to use G2plot (https://g2plot.antv.vision/) for a basic line graph. I made some tests a while ago with the 1.28 version and it was working fine. I removed some config that became obsolete and tried the latest version but the display of the graph isn't the same and looks like something sketchy.
I guess I made a mistake but I can't see which one, any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Here is a link to the sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/szzhq?file=/index.ts

I found a screenshot of what it used to look like with the same data :
https://ibb.co/H2MkfFj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, the x field needed to be set as a string instead of a number..

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't convert it to a string.
Use `meta` instead and declare your axis as `linear` type.

```
  meta: {
    CountPerSecund: {
      type: "linear"
    }
  },
```

You can also directly add a `type` property to `xAxis`
This is also working

```
xAxis: {
  type: 'linear',
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-wing-8bzyf6?file=/index.ts:51883-51946)